# Low Performance while running Tensorflow Benchmark Test on CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, benchmarking

I'm running TensorFlow benchmark on a single Motherboard Pro WS C246-ACE (Processor: i9-i9900K, DRAM: 64GB), just trying out the performance without using GPUs. But the performance is quick low. 2.5~3.5 image/sec.

Even after 20000 epochs of training, the max top-1/top-5 accuracy is about 0.031/0.094. Learning_rate is still rising in the same speed.

Is this the expected performance or did I use the wrong parameters?

`tf.__version__=1.15.0-dev20190821`

TensorFlow benchmarks Script
https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks/tree/master/scripts/tf_cnn_benchmarks

Below is my script:

```
python tf_cnn_benchmarks.py --num_gpus=1 \
  --batch_size=32 --model=resnet50_v1.5 \
  --variable_update=parameter_server --device=cpu \
  --data_format=NHWC --data_name=imagenet \
  --data_dir=F:\ILSVRC2017_CLS-LOC --save_summaries_steps=10 \
  --train_dir=C:\Users\C246_0710\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\benchmarks-master\scripts\tf_cnn_benchmarks\training \
  --summary_verbosity=1 --print_training_accuracy \
  --benchmark_log_dir=C:\Users\C246_0710\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\benchmarks-master\scripts\tf_cnn_benchmarks\training \
  --save_model_steps=1000
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What does Tensorflow log? Does it say e.g. that your CPU supports features it's not compiled to use?